# MongoDB - JSON schema validation

Tags: mongodb, next.js, json-schema-validator

Can anyone please tell me where to place the $jsonSchema in the following code. Every time I test post my code returns the status(400) success: false.

All I'm trying to do is validator the title and description have been entered correctly.

```
import { connectToDatabase } from "../../../util/mongodb";
export default async (req, res) => {
  const { method } = req;
  const { db } = await connectToDatabase();

  switch (method) {
    case "GET":
      try {
        const products = await db.collection("products").find({}).toArray();
        res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: products });
      } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({ sucess: false });
      }
      break;
    case "POST":
      try {
        const product = await db
          .collection("products")
          .insertOne(req.body)
          .runCommand({
            collMod: "products",
            validator: {
              $jsonSchema: {
                bsonType: "object",
                required: ["title", "description"],
                properties: {
                  title: {
                    bsonType: "string",
                    description: "must be a string and is required",
                    unique: true,
                  },
                  description: {
                    bsonType: "string",
                    description: "must be a string and is required",
                  },
                },
              },
            },
          });

        res.status(201).json({ success: true, data: product });
      } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({ sucess: false });
      }
      break;
    default:
      res.status(400).json({ dsucess: false });
      break;
  }
};
```

Comment: Did you try and see if your validator works fine with insert code using the values from the req.body - outside of the POST request (maybe from `mongo` shell).

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand what you mean. I'm a noob and self-taught. Can you explain further please?